# The parameter 'from' cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: from

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Ok, so basically I have a comments form on my website. People but comments in the comment box and it emails the comments to my email. The email part works fine and goes through. However, the error comes when I try to clear the form fields. It gives me an error saying:

**Error: The parameter 'from' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: from**

So anyone have any thoughts? like I said the email part works fine its just clearing the fields is giving me trouble

here is the code:

```
Imports System.Web.Mail
Imports System.Text

Partial Class Pages_ContactUs : Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim body As String = "From: " + YourName.Text + " " + Environment.NewLine + "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Message: " + Environment.NewLine + Comments.Text

    Dim MM As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    MM.EnableSsl = True
    MM.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("myEmail@gmail.com", "myPassword")
    MM.Credentials = cred
    MM.Send(YourEmail.Text, "myEmail@gmail.com", Subject.Text, body)
    ClearFields()
    lblEmail.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
    lblEmail.Text = "Your message has been sent successfuly"
    lblEmail.Visible = True

 End Sub

 Protected Sub ClearFields()
    YourName.Text = ""
    YourEmail.Text = ""
    Comments.Text = ""
    Subject.Text = ""
 End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You must supply it, just make it yours. Basic pattern:

```
Using SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
  Using mail As New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage()
    Try
      SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = True
      SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
      SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(un, pw)
      SmtpServer.Port = 25
      SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.address"
      mail.From = New MailAddress(sender)
      mail.To.Add(some address)
      mail.Subject = subject
      mail.Body = body
      mail.Sender = New MailAddress(sender)
      SmtpServer.Send(mail)
    Catch 
    End Try
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: that didnt work for me. it says 'MailMessage' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Net.Mail, System.Web.Mail'

Comment: Use the fully qualified namespace.

Comment: ok now it says my username and password are not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: That is for you to fill out! sender, un, and pw as facticious variables for demo only.

Comment: yea I have done that. Now when I fill out the form and hit send the page just stays loading. it doesn't finish loading.